# Iraq IDP/Refugee Camps

Tags: data-request, geospatial, releasing-data, global

Where can I find an updated data set on refugee and internally displaced camps in Iraq? UN OCHA has one from 2014, but it's too old. REACH has one but it holds no geographic information.

I'm working on a triangulation project, so coordinates -- or enough present info to scrap coordinates from the web -- are important. Any ideas?